# MySQL insert fails with 'column cannot be null' but column is not null

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with 323 rows freshly imported from a mysqldump off version mysql 5.7.27 which I import into my development copy running 5.7.24.

```
Server version      5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 day 20 hours 18 min 50 sec


mysql> select count(*) from json_idx_video_lookup;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      323 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table json_idx_video_lookup;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_idx_video_lookup | CREATE TABLE `json_idx_video_lookup` (
  `cs_objects_ref` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'object this entry points back to',
  `domain_ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(4096) NOT NULL COMMENT 'value being indexed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cs_objects_ref`),
  KEY `idx_value` (`value`(250)),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_json_idx_video_lookup_cs_objects_ref` FOREIGN KEY (`cs_objects_ref`) REFERENCES `cs_objects` (`cs_objects_ref`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am having a problem with two specific rows irrespective of mysql version. (Same happens if I try the import into Mysql 8.)

```
+----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| cs_objects_ref | domain_ref | value                                                        |
+----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|          12239 |          2 | ::WhQVRfYoztg                                                |
|          12751 |          2 | ::WhQVRfYoztg                                                |

mysql> SELECT * FROM json_idx_video_lookup where cs_objects_ref = 12239;
+----------------+------------+---------------+
| cs_objects_ref | domain_ref | value         |
+----------------+------------+---------------+
|          12239 |          2 | ::WhQVRfYoztg |
+----------------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to delete this row and re-insert it:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM json_idx_video_lookup WHERE cs_objects_ref = 12239;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO json_idx_video_lookup ( cs_objects_ref, domain_ref, value ) VALUES ( 12239, 2, '::WhQVRfYoztg' );
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'cs_objects_ref' cannot be null
```

??

Now if I delete the entry after this one:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM json_idx_video_lookup WHERE cs_objects_ref = 12751;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO json_idx_video_lookup ( cs_objects_ref, domain_ref, value ) VALUES ( 12239, 2, '::WhQVRfYoztg' );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

However, other rows in the same table do not exhibit the same behavior:

```
mysql> select * from json_idx_video_lookup where cs_objects_ref = 66629;
+----------------+------------+----------------------+
| cs_objects_ref | domain_ref | value                |
+----------------+------------+----------------------+
|          66629 |          2 | youtube::EiYvBFQvVRE |
+----------------+------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from json_idx_video_lookup where cs_objects_ref = 66629;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO json_idx_video_lookup ( cs_objects_ref, domain_ref, value ) VALUES ( 66629, 2, 'youtube::EiYvBFQvVRE' );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Apparently, I cannot delete and re-insert different rows with the same value field but I do not have a UNIQUE key on the value field. Regardless, if it were a UNIQUE key issue I should get a duplicate key error.

If I use the same CREATE TABLE command as above just changing the name of the table to create a fresh table, I am able to run the insert commands without error.

I do not understand. What am I missing? Mysql Bug?

Comment: This is from a fresh import from a mysqldump file ...

Comment: No triggers. The same behavior happens on multiple physical machines with different OSes as well.

Comment: *The same behavior happens on multiple physical machines* It is repraducable? Excellent. Create a fiddle with described problem, please...